# Cassandra custom consistency on multi data center setup

Tags: cassandra, consistency

We would like to create following configuration:
3 data centres: 2 to serve web servers and 1 for analytic

Number of write/read is expected to be around 10%/90%,
writes was going to be done on EACH_QUORUM, 
reads was going to be done on LOCAL_QUORUM

The problem is that we would like to do EACH_QUORUM on 2 clusters, but not the analytic one

Question: is it possible to setup such configuration in Cassandra?

Note: as most close solution out of the box we see possibility to change to LOCAL_QUORUM for writes, but it is a bit different to what we need as perfect solution

Comment: Please clarify what are you going to do: `EACH_QUORUM` means quorum in each data center (https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/interface/thrift/gen-java/org/apache/cassandra/thrift/ConsistencyLevel.java#L65); if you want to use quorum in those two clusters, what consistency level do you expect to be for the analytic one?

Comment: We expect that analytic data center would receive updates as part of data replication, as in http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/c-summit-2013-eventual-consistency-hopeful-consistency-by-christos-kalantzis , and in analytic data center consistency level would be ONE for read (and no writes)